Masses on a light string passing through smooth rings.
One end of a light string is fixed at a point $A$. The string passes through a small smooth ring $B$ fixed at the same level as $A$.
A particle of mass $m$ hangs freely from the other end of the string. A smooth ring $C$, also of mass $m$ , is free to slide on the string between $A$ and $B$, and the system is in equilibrium. Show that $AC$ and $BC$ are both inclined at an angle $ \frac{ \pi}{3} $ to the vertical.

My workings:
From what I know, smooth rings means tension in the string will be the same along the whole length? And with the system in equilibrium, the forces for each mass can be analysed separately?
For mass hanging on string through ring at $B$: $T_{1} = W$
At $C$ Horizontally: $T_{1} \cos( \alpha) = T_{1} \cos( \beta) \Rightarrow \cos( \alpha) =\cos( \beta)$
At $C$ Vertically: $W = T_{1} \sin( \alpha) + T_{1} \sin( \beta)$
Please can anyone be kind to advise me from here, because I don't think I'm on the right track. Not sure about the tension throughout the string?

Yes you’re on the right track, you can go ahead to find alpha beta as 30 degrees, that would imply ac and bc inclined to vertical at 60 degrees

Ahhh, am I right seeing that at C vertically, (with T1 = W for mass hanging at B), we get sin(a) + sin(b) = 1? Hence a = b = 30 degs

We know that the tension in the string is $mg$ because the mass below $B$ is at equilibrium.
If we sum the horizontal forces at point $C$, we get that $$T_1\cos{\alpha}=T_1\cos{\beta}\implies\cos{\alpha}=\cos{\beta}$$
From this, we get that $\alpha = \beta$ because both angles are between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$
Summing the forces in the vertical direction at $C$ gives $$2T_1\sin{\alpha}=mg\implies 2mg\sin{\alpha}=mg\implies\sin{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}\implies \alpha=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
The angle $\alpha$ is the horizontal angle so the vertical angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Many thanks John Douma.

@Nik You're welcome.
